# Firebase analytics not give more than 30 minutes data

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I implemented firebase to my Unity game. I use event tracking code as in the format of:

Eventname(eventid, eventparameter, parametervalue)

Eventid-> something like 'level1_1'

Eventparameter -> different parameters in eac case, 'gameovertype', 'winscore' etc

Parametervalue -> string or number for different cases

I am testing since 2 weeks and I have following problems:

[image]

1- Stremview show user data that I needed(gives parameter values and track each user) but it stores users for 30 minutes and cannot reached at this format after. How can I view them later?

2- I look for 'User properties' part but it says 'data is not available for this part'. How can I see the user properties?

3- In events section, I could not view the parameter values under each event. It only show total parameter value in some cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. You cannot view stream view data after 30 minutes.
2. I'm not sure what the problem is. It's probably the user property has not been set for those events, in case the code to set user properties might not have been reached in production code.
3. You can track events' parameters so they can be displayed on the Dashboard. See https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489