# How to show data greater then 30 mins on firebase console?

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-console

[image]

How we can increase the right side event timeline greater than 30 mins!

Comment: The time period for this view cannot be extended afaik. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437868/firebase-analytics-not-give-more-than-30-minutes-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase analytics not give more than 30 minutes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437868/firebase-analytics-not-give-more-than-30-minutes-data)